# Java Android issue on JSONParser when nextInt()

Tags: java, android

I have an issue which seems very easy but I don't know where it could came from...
I have the following JSon:

```
{
  "meters": 1000,
  "ivs": 95
}
```

I have the code:

```
    JsonReader jsonreader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    jsonreader.beginObject();
    while(jsonreader.hasNext()){
        String name = jsonreader.nextName();
        switch(name){
            case "meters": {jsonreader.nextInt(); // CRASH HERE}
            case "ivs": {jsonreader.nextInt(); // CRASH HERE}
            default: {jsonreader.skipValue();}
        }
    }
    jsonreader.endObject();
    jsonreader.close();
```

When I mute the case lines, it's okay. The following code works:

```
    JsonReader jsonreader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    jsonreader.beginObject();
    while(jsonreader.hasNext()){
        String name = jsonreader.nextName();
        switch(name){
            //case "meters": {jsonreader.nextInt(); // CRASH HERE}
            //case "ivs": {jsonreader.nextInt(); // CRASH HERE}
            default: {jsonreader.skipValue();}
        }
    }
    jsonreader.endObject();
    jsonreader.close();
```

But I don't know why when I uncomment one of those values, the code doesn't work.

Edit: I tried to debug, the name value is well "meters" or "ivs", and I tried to insert "jsonreader.hasNext()" before "nextInt()" inside both cases and it answered true, then crashes at "nextInt()" as it does usually.

Comment: Describe "code doesn't work", and put that description in the body of the question. Have you tried to debug this? e.g., just print/log what you get for `name` https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You will also want to review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to debug, I put it in the edit section.

Comment: What's the exact exception message you get?

Comment: @Uphaze so, you've proven that you are entering the while loop. Now move from the known to the unknown to discover the bug. No one is going to debug your code for you.

Comment: I do not have any exception message... I don't know how to put it in Android Studio: all I have is that my GUI is in the emulator when I remove the "case" values, and not when I remove them (blank screen). How could I have an exception message?

Comment: You say you have a "crash". The emulator will show you the stacktrace for the crash in logcat. In Android Studio you should have the Android Monitor tab open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `switch` statement:

```
switch(name){
    case "meters": {jsonreader.nextInt();}
    case "ivs": {jsonreader.nextInt();}
    default: {jsonreader.skipValue();}
}
```

Switch statements are a little different from `if-then` blocks because execution *falls through* case statements. When a case is matched, execution jumps to that point and then continues as normal, regardless of other case labels. When you hit the first case ("meters"), you read an `int` from the JSON. But then execution continues, and you read another `int` (from the "ivs" case), and then you ignore a value (in the default case), but at that point there's no value to ignore, so your code crashes. To keep execution from falling through, you need to include `break` statements at the end of each case.

Your code should look something like this:

```
switch(name) {
    case "meters":
        jsonreader.nextInt();
        break;
    case "ivs":
        jsonreader.nextInt();
        break;
    default:
        jsonreader.skipValue();
        break; // This one's technically optional because there's nothing to
               // fall through to, but including it makes your code cleaner
               // and more consistent
}
```